# process.env is undefined after using .env file in react project

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts, .env

process.env is undefined after using .env file in react project.
The solutions that I found online did not resolve the error and it still persists after using "react-scripts": "5.0.1", "react-error-overlay": "^6.0.11" and "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions".

```
<GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}>
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hidden",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.14",
    "@react-oauth/google": "^0.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "date-and-time": "^2.4.3",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-particles": "^2.9.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.2",
    "tsparticles": "^2.9.3",
    "web-vitals": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}",
    "prettify": "prettier --write src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,md,json,scss} --config ./.prettierrc",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "prettier": "2.8.7",
    "react-error-overlay": "^6.0.11"
  }
}
```

Error:

[image: Error]

Folder Structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your env key name to `REACT_APP_GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID` as react requires `REACT_APP_` as prefix, then restart the run process